# Linear Regression Prediction on Python3

Tags: python-3.x, linear-regression, prediction

I am trying to use LinearRegression on a data set using Python 3. I am trying to see the influence of Order Size on the metric OTIF (On Time In Full). The metric is a percentage of the amount of deliveries delivered in on time and in full. I get an error when I try to use LinearRegression.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# path of data
path = 'c:/Data/ame.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(path)
df.head()

from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
lm = LinearRegression
lm

X = df[['Order Units']]
Y = df['OTIF%']

lm.fit(X,Y)

Yhat=lm.predict(X)
Yhat[0:5]

 ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-39-b4b21bd8b84e> in <module>
----> 1 Yhat=lm.predict(X)
  2 Yhat[0:5]

TypeError: predict() missing 1 required positional argument: 'X'
```

Answer (score 0):

I think issue is you are not creating LinearRegression object for you.you must call its own constructor to get a object of the class.try this.

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
lm = LinearRegression()
X = df[['Order Units']]
Y = df['OTIF%']

lm.fit(X,Y)

Yhat=lm.predict(X)
```